# Why do we write $t$ as $ct$ in special relativity?

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, units, dimensional-analysis

We commonly write 4-vectors as $x=(x^0,x^1,x^2,x^3)$, where $x^0=ct$ rather than $x^0=t$. The only reason I can think of why this was done is to write everything in spatial dimensions. That is dimensional analysis of $ct$ gives $\frac{[m]}{[s]}\cdot[s]$, such that it is easy to define invariants like $(\Delta s)^2$. I'm curious however, is there another reason why it is convenient to use such notation?

Comment: Maybe it is easier to draw a light-cone.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the reason is because you want to write every component with the same physical dimension. It wouldn't make any sense to have vector components with different dimensions, even for the more common three dimensional vectors.
Furthermore with this notation you can directly apply the Lorentz transformations simply by the multipication of a matrix (that is the same for every 4-vector) with the the vector you want to trasform.

If you don't write the component of a 4-vector in a way they have different dimensions you would have to correct the matrix every time. This is obvioulsy very uncomfortable.