# Why is the fourth spacetime coordinate of an event a spatial coordinate ($ct$)?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, dimensional-analysis

I'm starting to study the derivations of the Lorentz transformations on the following wikipedia page:

[Derivations of The Lorentz Transformations/Physical principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivations_of_the_Lorentz_transformations#Physical_principles)

And I came across something that puzzles me. In the subsection 'Physical principles/The second postulate', the writer assigns an event the set of coordinates $x_{1}, y_{1}, z_{1}, ct_{1}$.

Shouldn't an event have a set of coordinates $(x,y,z,t)$? What is the meaning of assigning a fourth spatial dimension ($ct$)?

Is it just for mathematical convenience? That is, when computing spacetime intervals, the factor $c$ must be there in order for the rest of the theory to be consistent in terms of dimensions of the equations?

(The same assignment comes up when the position four-vector is defined: $X^{\mu}=(ct,\mathbf{x})$. Aren't position four-vectors labellers of spacetime points, i.e, events?)

Comment: Also see [Why do we write t as ct in special relativity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/314767/). But basically yes, it's mathematical convenience.

Comment: Thank you @Jonas. It makes sense now. Sorry for the duplicate!